# Parsing a JSON Array into a Java array returns the last element as the second index

Tags: java, android, json

So I'm working with a local JSON file, and when I try to parse it into a Java data structure everything goes fine except as the title suggests, the last element of the JSON array is returned as the second element of the Java array

```
        "text": [
            {
                "0": "text"
            }, {
                "3": "text"
            }, {
                "5": "text:"
            }, {
                "6": "text:"
            }, {
                "7": "text:"
            }, {
                "8": "text"
            }, {
                "9": "text:"
            }, {
                "9": "text"
            }, {
                "10": "text:"
            }, {
                "11": ""
            }
        ]
```

```
   for(int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
                    String index = content.getJSONObject(j).names().get(0).toString();
                    String ToCVal = content.getJSONObject(j).getString(index);
                    temp_hashmap.put(index, ToCVal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not a problem with the JsonObject, its a problem with HashMap you have to use 
[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to save the order